# axios get - multiple api calls with response from first api to subsequent calls

Tags: axios

How to make multiple api calls with axios - when I have to pass a value from my first api response to all subsequent calls. I have 2 other calls to be made inside `getData` function where I have to pass a value from y first api response `{data}` - how to chain multipl requests with axios? 2 next calls are dependent on first call - they are not dependant on each other - they can happen in parallel - the only issue I have is - I am not able to pass the response data to the subsequent end-points.

```
import Request from 'axios';

export function getData() {
  return async function getData(dispatch) {
    const { data } = await getDatafromService();
    dispatch({ type: 'Data_fetch', payload: data });
  };
}

async function getDatafromService() {
  const endpoint = "api-url";
  return Request.get(endpoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for an overall structure.

The async function getData will ultimately return an array of the responses from the last two requests.

```
import Request from 'axios';

export function getData() {
  return async function getData(dispatch) {
    const { data } = await getDatafromService();
    return Promise.all([
      sendDataToFirstService(data),
      sendDataToSecondService(data),
    ])
  };
}

function getDatafromService() {
  const endpoint = "api-url";
  return Request.get(endpoint);
}

function sendDataToFirstService(data) {
  const endpont =  "first-url";
  return Request.post(endpoint, data)
}

function sendDataToSecondService(data) {
  const endpont =  "second-url";
  return Request.post(endpoint, data)
}
```

Note that you may need to modify the data received from the original `get` request before passing it to the next two.

You can do this by chaining `.then` onto the Promise like so...

```
function getDatafromService() {
  const endpoint = "api-url";
  return Request.get(endpoint).then(({data}) => modify(data));
}
```